# Excel formulário (Bloquear campos)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Tenho uma dúvida em relação a que fórmula posso usar.

Tenho uma caixa com 3 opções (Exemplo: 1 , 2 , 3) e caso eu selecione a **opção 1** posso preencher o **campo 1** e estão bloqueadas as **opções 2** e **3**. 
Caso selecione a **opção 2** posso preencher o **campo 2** e estão bloqueadas as **opções 1** e **3**.

Sei que é algo simples mas não me lembro da forma de o fazer. 
Caso me possam dar umas ideias agradeço.

[image: a caixa que tenho com opções]

Answer (score 0):

Isto é possível com a utilização do VBA.

Após inserir os botões de opção OptionButton1, OptionButton2 e OptionButton3. O seguinte código pode ser inserido no formulário:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    OptionButton1 = False
    OptionButton2 = False
    OptionButton3 = False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()
  TextBox1.Locked = False
  TextBox1.Visible = True
  Label1.Visible = True

  TextBox2.Locked = True
  TextBox2.Visible = False
  Label2.Visible = False

  TextBox3.Locked = True
  TextBox3.Visible = False
  Label3.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Change()
  TextBox2.Locked = False
  TextBox2.Visible = True
  Label2.Visible = True

  TextBox1.Locked = True
  TextBox1.Visible = False
  Label1.Visible = False

  TextBox3.Locked = True
  TextBox3.Visible = False
  Label3.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Change()
  TextBox3.Locked = False
  TextBox3.Visible = True
  Label3.Visible = True

  TextBox2.Locked = True
  TextBox2.Visible = False
  Label2.Visible = False

  TextBox1.Locked = True
  TextBox1.Visible = False
  Label1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

O formulário possui 3 Labels, 3 Textboxes e 3 OptionButtons, como na imagem a seguir:

[image: Imagem do formulário.]

#### EDIT:

Para bloquear a célular com option button na Planilha, cada macro deverá ser atribuída à cada botão de opção.

```
Sub Botãodeopção1_Clique()
  Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B1").Locked = False
  Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B2").Locked = True
  Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B3").Locked = True
End Sub
Sub Botãodeopção2_Clique()
  Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B1").Locked = True
  Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B2").Locked = False
  Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B3").Locked = True
End Sub
Sub Botãodeopção3_Clique()
  Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B1").Locked = True
  Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B2").Locked = True
  Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B3").Locked = False
End Sub
```

#### EDIT2:

Usando uma Caixa de Combinação de controle Activex e alterando a Propriedade `ListFillRange` para o local dos dados, utilize este código:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    'Declarar Planilha
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1")

    If ComboBox1.Value = 1 Then
        With ws
            .Unprotect Password:="SuaSenha"
            .Cells.Locked = False
            .Cells.FormulaHidden = False
            Range("B2").Locked = True
            Range("B2").Value = 0
            Range("B3").Locked = True
            Range("B3").Value = 0
            .Protect Password:="SuaSenha"
        End With
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = 2 Then
        With ws
            .Unprotect Password:="SuaSenha"
            .Cells.Locked = False
            .Cells.FormulaHidden = False
            Range("B1").Locked = True
            Range("B1").Value = 0
            Range("B3").Locked = True
            Range("B3").Value = 0
            .Protect Password:="SuaSenha"
        End With
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = 3 Then
        With ws
            .Unprotect Password:="SuaSenha"
            .Cells.Locked = False
            .Cells.FormulaHidden = False
            Range("B1").Locked = True
            Range("B1").Value = 0
            Range("B2").Locked = True
            Range("B2").Value = 0
            .Protect Password:="SuaSenha"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Em que Trava as células desejadas dependendo do valor inserido na ComboBox.

Comment: Só dessa forma correcto? 
Ou tambem consigo em VBA bloquear a célula ?

Comment: Você pode bloquear células com: `Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B2:C3").Locked = True`

Comment: Estou a usar o campo validação dos dados para fazer a lista com as varias opçoes

Comment: e se quiser colocar o valor de 0 nos campos bloqueados

Comment: Alterei o código, veja e altere para suas necessidades

Answer (score 0):

Não seria mais simples substituir a caixa por uma célula que somente aceitasse as opções 1, 2 ou 3? Abaixo poderia haver um pequeno quadro explicando o que são as 3 opções.